# Dart - how to pass a function as an argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass a function as a parameter of a widget which contains a button (the function passed will be executed on the `onPressed` of the button)

```
myFunction1(){
   // do some things
}

myWidget(Function onPress){
    return FlatButton(
    onPressed : onPress,
    );
}
```

and then calling `myWidget(myFunction1)`. But it doesn't work and I believe it's normal. The function is right executed and try to give a result. But I don't want the function to be executed now for it's result, I kind of want to pass the 'reference" of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Widget myWidget(Function onPress){
      return FlatButton(
          onPressed : onPress,
          child: Text('Button'),
      );
  }


 myWidget((){
//your code...
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('First Screen'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: myWidget(myFunction1),
  ),
 );
}

myFunction1() {
  print('called');
}

myWidget(Function onPressed) {
 return FlatButton(
   child: Text('FlatButton'),
   onPressed: onPressed,
 );
}
```